# BLDC CW/CCW rotation issue

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I wrote the post with BLDC delta winding commutation sequence, and to this day a believe the findings are true.

But i have an issue that is occurring only in CCW rotation, at about 97% up to 100% duty cycle the motor starts to run rough but at a slight higher RPM (2600 to 3000) in short bursts (like it would have timing advance for short periods).

This is not happening on CW rotation, the RPM is the same in CW vs CCW up to 97% duty cycle, but above that in CCW there is the simptome described.

The strange thing is that this is NOT related to load nor to supply voltage (it is doing the same at 10, 20 even at 100 Amps and at 24, 37, 74 Volts supply), the only relation to the simptome i found is the duty cycle (above 97%).

Note the motor is run in sensor mode with no timing advance (not in SW not in HW), there is no cross conduction, all the drive signals on the gates check out fine the only thing that is a bit strange is that the phase wave forms look different (some pulses in the wrong places) in CW vs CCW, and i can not figure out why. I added a few scope images, they are measured with ground on U phase and channel A and B on V and W phase of the motor.

The question is, what causes the described simptom?

Photo nr 1  CW rotation duty cycle 100% NO simptome.

Photo nr 2  CCW rotation duty cycle 100% WITH simptome.

Photo nr 3  CW rotation duty cycle about 95% NO simptome.

Photo nr 4  CCW rotation duty cycle about 85% NO simptome.

Photo nr 5  CCW rotation duty cycle about 97% WITH simptome.

[image: photo nr 1 CW rotation duty cycle 100% NO simptome]
[image: photo nr 2 CCW rotation duty cycle 100% WITH simptome]
[image: photo nr 3 CW rotation duty cycle about 95% NO simptome]
[image: photo nr 4 CCW rotation duty cycle about 85% NO simptome]
[image: photo nr 5 CCW rotation duty cycle about 97% WITH simptome]

Comment: The question is, what causes the described simptom?

Comment: please do not put questions in comments ... add the question to your post

Comment: Start with what is causing the pulses in the wrong place. That would be what is likely your underlying issue. There may be assumptions in the code that break in the opposite direction. And may cause issues at lower duty cycles but the effect is more noticeable at higher ones.

Comment: Well, i tested with function generetor (without motor) on the hall input, and i found that there is quite a delay between the time input changes and the output changes, most of the time is 2us, but from time to time there is up to 7us and in CCW mode the delay is about 1 to 2 us longer, now at 3000RPM on comutation is 166us long, that delay crates a bit of timing retard but i dont think is long enough to create the simptom.... I'l have to do the same measurements today hith the motor driving the input to see if there us a difference, be couse the motor phases shows a possible delay up to 32us.

Comment: Well, same results with motor, and the delay si about the same in CW vs CCW mode, so.... I have to come with other plan to continue..... This is baffling

Answer (score 2):

Well, after 3 months of head bashing, I concluded that there is nothing wrong with the controller.

If I swap the motor phases, I can make the motor run ok in CCW mode on controller and motor spinning CW, and make it run bad on CW mode on controller and motor spinning CCW.

So when the motor spins CCW it seems the sensor output is not the same as spinning CW, according to BEMF and hall output, for a 5.358 ms pulse when motor spins CW there is 2.5 degres or 4.1% of timing advance, and in CCW the same values are timing retard, witch apparently is enough to cause the symptom.

And one thing that I did not pay attention, even that the simptom was present at low supply voltages as well as high voltages, when increasing voltage the simptom was worsening because the motor was increasing speed and the timing retard is fixed (halls physical position) so the faster is spins the greater the timing retard.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! It is useful to others with similar issues.